# Не подключается htaccess

Tags: ubuntu, .htaccess, apache

как всегда вот film.lc.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName film.lc
    ServerAlias www.film.lc
    DocumentRoot /var/www/film.lc/
    <Directory «/var/www/film.lc»>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/www/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

это тоже далал `sudo a2enmod rewrite` 
такое дело AccessFileName .htaccess в apache.conf присутствует
но все равно набираю film.lc и вываливатеся список файлов и папок сайта но не как не сам сайт
вот сам htaccess если что

```
cmOptions +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if request begins with /admin remove admin and ad /backend/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin/?(.*) /backend/web/$1

# other requests add /frontend/web/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend/web|backend/web|admin)
RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/web/$1

# if frontend request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php

# if backend request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /backend/web/index.php

php_value max_execution_time 3000
```

Comment: 1. кавычки `«...»` исправьте на `"..."` или, лучше, вообще уберите. 2. программу перезапускали?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin действительно в кавычках проблема пишите ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

согласно [документации](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory):

> Directory paths *may* be quoted, if you like, however, it *must* be quoted if the path contains spaces. This is because a space would otherwise indicate the end of an argument.

вольный перевод:

> пути в директиве `directory` *могут* быть ограничены кавычками, и *должны* быть ограничены кавычками, если содержат пробелы. потому что пробел рассматривается как конец аргумента.

в качестве примера приводится использование двойных кавычек:

```
<directory "путь">
```

практика показывает, что и одинарные кавычки интерпретируются программой *apache* аналогичным образом — в качестве ограничителей аргументов.

а вот кавычки-ёлочки `«` и `»`, использованные в приведённом в вопросе файле:

```
<Directory «/var/www/film.lc»>
```

вероятно, рассматриваются программой как *часть* аргумента, а не как *ограничители*.